# Android - TableRow with same width and wrap text view

Tags: android, textview

I am working on project where I want to have data (`TextView`) in table. I want to have table with 3 columns each of them take the same space and wrap the text in them. Like for example in `MS Excel` when you press **wrap text**. I have to do this **programmatically**.

Comment: have you tried any thisg for this.

Comment: I tried to set `android:shrinkColumns="*"`. But if some text contents more text then the other. TextView with lesser text is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

**How**:

```
yourTextViewComponnent.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```